# Removing elements from JSON based on a condition in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string that I want to be able to amend in C#.  I want to be able to delete a set of data based when one of the child values is a certain value.

Take the following

```
 {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "explainOther":"",
      "fl":"*,score",
      "indent":"on",
      "start":"0",
      "q":"*:*",
      "hl.fl":"",
      "qt":"",
      "wt":"json",
      "fq":"",
      "version":"2.2",
      "rows":"2"}
  },
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":
  [{
        "id":"438500feb7714fbd9504a028883d2860",
        "name":"John",
        "dateTimeCreated":"2012-02-07T15:00:42Z",
        "dateTimeUploaded":"2012-08-09T15:30:57Z",
        "score":1.0
   },
   {
        "id":"2f7661ae3c7a42dd9f2eb1946262cd24",
        "name":"David",
        "dateTimeCreated":"2012-02-07T15:02:37Z",
        "dateTimeUploaded":"2012-08-09T15:45:06Z",
        "score":1.0
    }]
 }}
```

There are two response results shown above.  I want to be able to remove the whole parent response result group when its child "id" value is matched, for example if my id was "2f7661ae3c7a42dd9f2eb1946262cd24", I would want the second group to be deleted and thus my result would look as follows.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "explainOther":"",
      "fl":"*,score",
      "indent":"on",
      "start":"0",
      "q":"*:*",
      "hl.fl":"",
      "qt":"",
      "wt":"json",
      "fq":"",
      "version":"2.2",
      "rows":"2"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[
  {
        "id":"438500feb7714fbd9504a028883d2860",
        "name":"John",
        "dateTimeCreated":"2012-02-07T15:00:42Z",
        "dateTimeUploaded":"2012-08-09T15:30:57Z",
        "score":1.0
    }]
  }}
```

I will need to perform multiple delete operations on the Json file.  The Json file could contain thousands of results and I really need the most performant way possible.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this so big that you'd worry about blowing the top off your memory if you read the whole JSON stream in at once?

Comment: It's a good shout, but it is most likely that the results will be paged to something more manageable like say 100 results in a page

Comment: Would there ever be a situation where you'd have to roll back a page to find something to delete?  It doesn't look like that's the case but I want to be sure.

Comment: No there would be no need to rollback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been attempting to compress this into a nicer LINQ statement for the last 10 minutes or so, but the fact that the list of known Ids is inherently changing how each element is evaluated means that I'm probably not going to get that to happen.

```
        var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        var docsToRemove = new List<JToken>();
        foreach (var doc in jObj["response"]["docs"])
        {
            var id = (string)doc["id"];
            if (knownIds.Contains(id))
            {
                docsToRemove.Add(doc);
            }
            else
            {
                knownIds.Add(id);
            }
        }
        foreach (var doc in docsToRemove)
            doc.Remove();
```

This seems to work well with the crappy little console app I spun up to test, but my testing was limited to the sample data above so if there's any problems go ahead and leave a comment so I can fix them.

For what it's worth, this will basically run in linear time with respect to how many elements you feed it, which is likely all the more algorithmic performance you're going to get without getting hilarious with this problem.  Spinning each page of ~100 records off into its own task using the Task Parallel Library invoking a worker that will handle its own little page and returned the cleaned JSON string comes to mind.  That would certainly make this faster if you ran it on a multi-cored machine, and I'd be happy to provide some code to get you started on that, but it's also a huge overengineering for the scope of the problem as it's presented.

Comment: How did you test your code? `doc["id"]` throws an exception `Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.`

Comment: Hrm, that's odd.  Let me try to reproduce, see if there's something silly I overlooked when pasting the code out.

Comment: Haha, I'm such a dumbass sometimes.  My paste from my dev VM was stale.  That was actually code from one of my first attempts that ended in a horrible failure.  The first error, obviously, is that you should be enumerating `["docs"]` as well.  The other error lurking in that first bit of code is that you can't go modifying an `IEnumerable` while you're enumerating over it.  It took me a while to take another look at my answer to realize my mistake.  Updated now!

Answer (score 5):

```
var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
HashSet<string> idsToDelete = new HashSet<string>() { "2f7661ae3c7a42dd9f2eb1946262cd24" };

jObj["response"]["docs"]
    .Where(x => idsToDelete.Contains((string)x["id"]))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(doc=>doc.Remove());

var newJson = jObj.ToString();
```

Comment: The OP is hoping to do this for any given ID, so you'd have to keep a list of known IDs and evaluate each element serially, deleting them if the `List.Contains(id)` comes back true...but again, that presumes that the element is small enough that a simple `DeserializeObject` call won't cause an `OutOfMemoryException`!

Comment: @YYY I can extend the answer to delete multiple ids easily, but your comment about OOM is just your assumption. You create your own problems and expect me to answer it. I Only see in the question that there may be tousands of results .

Comment: Er, I don't understand your hostility - if you check the question, you'll note I am attempting to clarify the memory limitations, so I could attempt my own answer.  When told there are thousands of rows it is a reasonable question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above worked for me, I had to `Remove()` child from `Parent` (`.Parent.Remove()`) not just `Remove()` it. Working code example below:

```
namespace Engine.Api.Formatters
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    public class ReducedJson
    {
        public dynamic WriteToStreamAsync(object value)
        {
                    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(value);
                    var serializedJson = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                    foreach (var response in serializedJson["ProductData"]["Motor"]["QuoteResponses"])
                    {
                        response["NetCommResults"].Parent.Remove();
                        foreach (var netCommResult in response["BestPriceQuote"]["NetCommResults"])
                        {
                            netCommResult["Scores"].Parent.Remove();
                        }
                    }

          return serializedJson;
        }
}
```

Hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 0):

I just find another answer.

```
var aJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
var doc = aJson["response"]["docs"];
JObject docs = new JObject();
docs["docs"] = doc;

// remove
docs.SelectTokens(string.Format("docs[?(@.id == '{0}')]", "2f7661ae3c7a42dd9f2eb1946262cd24")).ToList().ForEach(i => i.Remove());
// replace
aJson.SelectToken("response.docs").Replace(docs["docs"]);
```