# How to find json token by value and then delete the token

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have, for example, a json like this in C# :

```
{
"Harry.firstName": "Harry",
"Harry.lastName": "Birimirski",
"Harry.recordTitle": "My title",
"Harry.SomeRepeatable": [{
        "GUID": "9dd8c7bb-64e1-452b-90d5-db2b6e505492",
        "NestedRepetable": [{
                "GUID": "05aa2161-fcc2-45a6-b0b7-8749d94a2e61",
                "nestedText": "Nested first"
            },
            {
                "GUID": "dfd67eeb-703b-4cc4-9321-b6a39084e687",
                "nestedText": "Nested first 2"
            }
        ],
        "name": "First"
    },
    {
        "GUID": "3318e544-1be8-4795-9bab-fa05de79cf46",
        "NestedRepetable": [{
            "GUID": "c1b60869-7c75-4af4-8037-be26aeca7939",
            "nestedText": "Nested second"
        }],
        "name": "Second"
    }
]
}
```

And I would like to remove item from `NestedRepetable` array by value.
For example remove element that contains GUID: `05aa2161-fcc2-45a6-b0b7-8749d94a2e61`, desired result will looks like :

```
{
"Harry.firstName": "Harry",
"Harry.lastName": "Birimirski",
"Harry.recordTitle": "My title",
"Harry.SomeRepeatable": [{
        "GUID": "9dd8c7bb-64e1-452b-90d5-db2b6e505492",
        "NestedRepetable": [
            {
                "GUID": "dfd67eeb-703b-4cc4-9321-b6a39084e687",
                "nestedText": "Nested first 2"
            }
        ],
        "name": "First"
    },
    {
        "GUID": "3318e544-1be8-4795-9bab-fa05de79cf46",
        "NestedRepetable": [{
            "GUID": "c1b60869-7c75-4af4-8037-be26aeca7939",
            "nestedText": "Nested second"
        }],
        "name": "Second"
    }
]
}
```

I've tried a couple of things with the help of Json.NET, but I cannot do it.
Keep in mind that the whole JSON structure is dynamic. The only thing that I know is the field name (GUID) in this case and the value in the field, that should be removed.

I've tried to do it in that way described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478767/removing-elements-from-json-based-on-a-condition-in-c-sharp), 
But they are using a hardcoded path of the json. That's not my case.

I've used the following code :

```
        private JToken RemoveFields(JToken token, string fieldValue)
    {
        JContainer container = token as JContainer;
        if (container == null)
        {
            return token;
        }

        List<JToken> removeList = new List<JToken>();
        foreach (JToken el in container.Children())
        {
            JProperty p = el as JProperty;
            if (p != null)// && fields.Contains(p.Name))
            {
                if (p.Value.ToString() == fieldValue)
                {
                    removeList.Add(el);

                    //try to remove the whole thing, not only GUID field ..
                    //removeList.Add(el.Parent);

                }
            }

            RemoveFields(el, fieldValue);
        }

        foreach (JToken el in removeList)
        {
            el.Parent.Remove();
            return token;
        }

        return token;
    }
```

But I'm receiving the following error :

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"

Probably because I'm trying to remove the parent element.

Comment: If it’s just one hit you can return after removing the object. Since you’re using an iterator (foreach does this) you can’t add or remove items while iterating and that causes issues. So would just returning after the removal work?

Comment: The example that you point at does the removing after the iteration is finished. Because you're calling the function recursively most likely what happens is that it finishes the inner iteration and tries to remove some elements, while the outer iteration is still in progress.Try building the list of items to remove and then make sure you remove them outside of any JSON traversing

Comment: Have you tried adding `ToList()` to your `removeList` iteration? Is that sufficient?

Comment: ToList() is not working for me, it's returning the whole token, without removed elements from the array. I agree with all of you - the problem is that the collection is modified, but i'm not able to find a way to return the proper result.

Comment: Something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39429965/3744182) seems close to what you want, which is to remove objects with a `"GUID"` property with a specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to find and remove objects that match the following criteria:

1. All objects contained by an array property named `"NestedRepetable"`
2. that have a property named `"GUID"` with a specific value.

The easiest way to do this will be to use [`JToken.SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) with a [JSONPath query](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm):

```
var value = "05aa2161-fcc2-45a6-b0b7-8749d94a2e61";

var queryStringTemplate = "..NestedRepetable[?(@.GUID == '{0}')]";
var query = root.SelectTokens(string.Format(queryStringTemplate, value));

foreach (var obj in query.ToList())
    obj.Remove();
```

If you don't actually care whether the objects are nested inside `"NestedRepetable"` (your question is unclear on this point) you can just do

```
var queryStringTemplate = "..[?(@.GUID == '{0}')]";
```

Notes:

- `..` is the *recursive descent* operator.  It descends the `JToken` hierarchy returning all values.
- `NestedRepetable` matches values of properties with the required name.
- `[?(@.GUID == '{0}')]` matches objects belonging to the `NestedRepetable` array with a property named `GUID` with the specified value.
- When removing tokens that match the query, it is necessary to materialize the query by calling `ToList()` to avoid the `Collection was modified` exception you are seeing.
- For more on JSONPath syntax see [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

Sample working .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/si5FPa) for the complex query and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HSurh0) for the simpler query.

Comment: This do the trick, thank you very much ! Different approach, but much clearer solution. Looks like i have to spend some time to get better understanding of JSONPath.